# auto-scaling not working in solr7.4 - autoaddreplica

Tags: solr, autoscaling

We're able to create new server via auto-scaling for our solr cluster 7.4 version. But the newly created server is not adding in our solr cluster automatically. Is there any settings or configurations we need to add in order to add the replica automatically in cluster for any collections.

commands used:
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=my_collection_3&numShards=1&replicationFactor=3&autoAddReplicas=true"

Currently 3 nodes are in our cluster and i'm trying to add 4th nod but its not getting added in solr 7.4 version. The same scenario is working fine in solr 7.5 version.

scaling policy used:

```
1)
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/autoscaling -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
 "set-cluster-policy" : [{
  "replica" : "1",
  "shard" : "#EACH",
  "node" : "#ANY",
 }]
}'

2)###Node Added Trigger
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/autoscaling -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
 "set-trigger": {
  "name" : "node_added_trigger",
  "event" : "nodeAdded",
  "waitFor" : "5s",
  "preferredOperation": "ADDREPLICA",
  "enabled" : true,
  "actions" : [
   {
    "name" : "compute_plan",
    "class": "solr.ComputePlanAction"
   },
   {
    "name" : "execute_plan",
    "class": "solr.ExecutePlanAction"
   }
  ]
 }
}'

3)###Node Lost Trigger
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/autoscaling -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
 "set-trigger": {
  "name" : "node_lost_trigger",
  "event" : "nodeLost",
  "waitFor" : "5s",
  "preferredOperation": "DELETENODE",
  "enabled" : true,
  "actions" : [
   {
    "name" : "compute_plan",
    "class": "solr.ComputePlanAction"
   },
   {
    "name" : "execute_plan",
    "class": "solr.ExecutePlanAction"
   }
  ]
 }
}'
```

Note the same policy(2,3) not working in 7.4

Errors:

```
[Mon Apr 08 11:52:00 UTC root@hawkeye-common ~]# curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/autoscaling -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
>  "set-trigger": {
>   "name" : "node_added_trigger",
>   "event" : "nodeAdded",
>   "waitFor" : "5s",
>   "preferredOperation": "ADDREPLICA",
>   "enabled" : true,
>   "actions" : [
>    {
>     "name" : "compute_plan",
>     "class": "solr.ComputePlanAction"
>    },
>    {
>     "name" : "execute_plan",
>     "class": "solr.ExecutePlanAction"
>    }
>   ]
>  }
> }'
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":5},
  "result":"failure",
  "WARNING":"This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.",
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject"],
    "details":[{
        "set-trigger":{
          "name":"node_added_trigger",
          "event":"nodeAdded",
          "waitFor":"5s",
          "preferredOperation":"ADDREPLICA",
          "enabled":true,
          "actions":[{
              "name":"compute_plan",
              "class":"solr.ComputePlanAction"},
            {
              "name":"execute_plan",
              "class":"solr.ExecutePlanAction"}]},
        "errorMessages":["Error validating trigger config node_added_trigger: TriggerValidationException{name=node_added_trigger, details='{preferredOperation=unknown property}'}"]}],
    "msg":"Error in command payload",
    "code":400}}
[Mon Apr 08 11:52:09 UTC root@hawkeye-common ~]#
[Mon Apr 08 11:52:16 UTC root@hawkeye-common ~]# curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/autoscaling -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{
>  "set-trigger": {
>   "name" : "node_lost_trigger",
>   "event" : "nodeLost",
>   "waitFor" : "5s",
>   "preferredOperation": "DELETENODE",
>   "enabled" : true,
>   "actions" : [
>    {
>     "name" : "compute_plan",
>     "class": "solr.ComputePlanAction"
>    },
>    {
>     "name" : "execute_plan",
>     "class": "solr.ExecutePlanAction"
>    }
>   ]
>  }
> }'
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1},
  "result":"failure",
  "WARNING":"This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.",
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject"],
    "details":[{
        "set-trigger":{
          "name":"node_lost_trigger",
          "event":"nodeLost",
          "waitFor":"5s",
          "preferredOperation":"DELETENODE",
          "enabled":true,
          "actions":[{
              "name":"compute_plan",
              "class":"solr.ComputePlanAction"},
            {
              "name":"execute_plan",
              "class":"solr.ExecutePlanAction"}]},
        "errorMessages":["Error validating trigger config node_lost_trigger: TriggerValidationException{name=node_lost_trigger, details='{preferredOperation=unknown property}'}"]}],
    "msg":"Error in command payload",
    "code":400}}
```

if any new sever added into that cluster the data(collection) must be added as a replica in that cluster.[AddReplica Automatically added in version 7.5]

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgEbL.png

Comment: The `preferredOperation` parameter wasn't introduced before Solr 7.5 - the [feature you're asking about (adding a new replica through the event triggers)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-12715) wasn't supported before 7.5. Before that the replicas were just moved from other, existing servers.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh,

Thanks for your update. So is there no possible way to add replica automatically in solr 7.4 cluster?

Regards,
Antony Johnson.

Comment: Not as as new replica, no - as far as I know. As detailed in the ticket, the previous behavior was that a replica was moved from an existing node instead of adding a new one.

Comment: MatsLindh ok understood,Thanks for the help